# Symfony passing 'login' to default parameter of route

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I added a default parameter to the route that is called after a user is authenticated. After running doctrine:fixtures:load to load new data I refreshed the page expecting it to take me to the login screen. However, it seems to be calling the route and passing 'login' to the default parameter.

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{sortOrder}", name="patient_order_index")
     * @param PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository
     * @param $sortOrder
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository, string $sortOrder = null)
    {

        $patients = $patientOrderRepository->getPatientsWithOrders($sortOrder);

        return $this->render('patient_order/index.html.twig', [
            'patient_orders' => $patients, 'sortOrder' => $sortOrder
        ]);
    }
```

I've tried checking to see if `$sortOrder` was = 'login' then redirecting and checking if user was fully authenticated but both sent me in infinite redirects.

Comment: I realized the 'login' was coming from the url parameter and was matching with that route. I've changed the route to patient_order/{sortOrder}, just need to figure out how to redirect to it once login is successful.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up needing two separate routes with different route names.

```
     * @Route("patient_order/orders/{sortOrder}", name="patient_order_index")
     * @Route("/", name="default_homepage")
     * @param PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository
     * @param $sortOrder
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository, string $sortOrder = null)
    {

        if($sortOrder == null) {
            $sortOrder = 'ASC';
        }

        $patients = $patientOrderRepository->getPatientsWithOrders($sortOrder);

        return $this->render('patient_order/index.html.twig', [
            'patient_orders' => $patients, 'sortOrder' => $sortOrder
        ]);
    }
```